# SQLite: choosing a unique separator

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a project that will result in an SQLite database of about 6 GB of text content (encoded UTF-8). The text will be diverse: it will have a great deal of plain text writing, but also a significant amount of special characters (tildes, backticks, section symbols, mdash's, endash's etc.). There will also be math formulas.

It looks like `.import` will be the load method.

Question: What could I use as an `.separator` value that won't be in my text?

I've grepped the future text with a few ideas and have not identified a separator that isn't in the actual content.

I suppose I could escape whatever separators may be in the text. But I prefer to avoid that option if I can.

Comment: What's the matter with | - i.e. the pipe symbol - it never occurs in normal text in any language that I've ever come across.You could also use ¬ (not sure what it's called) or ¦ (again, not sure of name) - both on the upper left of a Windows keyboard.

Comment: The pipe symbol comes up occasionally in math formulas, so that won't work. The not sign and broken bar might work. I'll check those.

Answer (score 3):

I was just about to suggest using a multi-character separator or a character from a foreign language (e.g. `日`) but `.separator` does not allow multi-character strings or even a multi-byte characters.

I would use a multi-character separator with very low probability to be in the text to import and then parse the document using a custom script. Here is an example in Python3 using `$$$$$$` as a separator, but consider strings like `[ŠĐć~^˘°˛˙€]` if needed.

*import.csv*

```
hello $$$$$$ world $$$$$$ 1
foo   $$$$$$ bar   $$$$$$ 2
```

*sqliteimport.py*

```
import sqlite3

import_file_name = "import.csv"
cell_separator = "$$$$$$"
lines = []
insert_query = "INSERT INTO imported (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
db_connection = sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite")
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
db_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE imported (a TEXT, b TEXT, c INTEGER);")
db_cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
with open(import_file_name, 'r') as import_file:
    for line in import_file:
        # Split each line at each cell_separator into a list of strings.
        # Strip each one of the columns to remove whitespaces.
        cleaned_columns = [column.strip()
                           for column in line.split(cell_separator)]
        db_cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(cleaned_columns))
db_connection.commit()
db_cursor.execute("VACUUM;")
db_cursor.close()
db_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use control characters as separators, e.g.

```
.separator ^A ^B
```

where ^A and ^B should be replaced by the corresponding control characters.

Answer (score 0):

As the content is encoded as UTF8, are you able to use "special" characters (those not present in ANSI) as your delimiter? I've had a similar problem working around SSIS in Azure not being able to deal with quoted commas in CSV by preprocessing the files to use a different delimiter. In the end I settled on ‖ (U+2016, double vertical bar) as it looks like a delimiter if the content needs to be visually inspected for debugging purposes. This may not be suitable for you as it may appear in your mathematical content, but there are many others you could try. Perhaps U+1F4A9 (pile of pop) which I initially used but moved away from in case the client accidentally saw the intermediate proceeding content, didn't like it, and didn't buy the "we had to pick a character you'd never use". That, and other emoji, might not be suitable if your corpus includes informal text. There are many uncommon punctuation symbols you could try (though many may fall foul of your mathematical content requirement) such as a flureon (❧). Also as others have suggested you could head for the other end of the table and use something from the control characters block like BEL (variously represented as \a, ^G, U+0007, ...).

> I suppose I could escape whatever separators may be in the text.

Because of the general nature of your target corpus I suspect that you will need to do this no matter what single character delimiter you choose, and probably for multi character options too. You never know when your chosen uncommon character(s) might randomly turn up in informal text (such as when people use them for text effects like ɘꙅɿɘvɘЯ and t̸̢͔̬͉̦̅̋ḧ̸̖͓͎̤̖̲͔͔̹̘͋̆̔͌̿͘ḯ̸̛̛͙͈͍̬̺̙͊͂s̴̩̮̓) or when they turn out to be used in international text either because they really are intended for that use or because some old encoding used them as a substitute for a character that was not yet available directly.